# AutoMapper: Convert Type for one Property

Tags: c#, automapper, dto-mapping

I use the following two classes for Entity and DTO:

```cs
public class VehicleEntity {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressNumber { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNumber { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string NumberPlacesStr { get; set; }
}

public class VehicleDto {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressNumber { get; set; }
    public string VehicleNumber { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int NumberPlaces { get; set; }
}
```

For Mapping, I use `AutoMapper` like

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<VehicleEnity, VehicleDto>()
```

This is working great. But the Property `NumberPlacesStr` is a `string` in the `VehicleEntity` and should be mapped to the `int` property `NumberPlaces` in the `VehicleDTO`. How can I configure this speciality?

Comment: Hi, what would be the `NumberPlacesStr` value? Will it only contains numeric character or?

Comment: The first issue, your properties have different names. So at first map the property names with `.ForMember()`.

Comment: @YongShun Yes only numeric characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.ForMember()` by specifying the source and destination property. Automapper will handle the casting from `string` to `int`.

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<VehicleEntity, VehicleDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NumberPlaces, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NumberPlacesStr));
```

---

However, the above approach may not work correctly if `NumberPlacesStr` is unable to be cast as `int`.

You may consider using the Custom Value Resolver for safe mapping and casting.

```cs
public class VehicleNumberPlacesResolver : IValueResolver<VehicleEntity, VehicleDto, int>
{
    public int Resolve(VehicleEntity source, VehicleDto destination, int member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            return Int32.Parse(source.NumberPlacesStr);
        }
        catch
        {
            return default;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<VehicleEntity, VehicleDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NumberPlaces, opt => opt.MapFrom<VehicleNumberPlacesResolver>());
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mbBaWb)

---

**References**

[Projection - AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Projection.html)

[Custom Value Resolvers - AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html)